# How do I make the player move towards the cursor Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have this 3D game I'm developing

In this game I am a roll of toilet paper

If I press space, I get yeeted towards the cursor

I started using raycasts to do this, but that didn't work out, AT ALL

So, how do I get the toilet paper to jump towards the cursor? (how do I get the direction for where the cursor is)

Comment: ' Towards the cursor'.... that makes no sense, the cursor is in screen space and the object is in 3D space... In fact your approach using rays is the correct, convert the cursor to 3D space, trace a ray to the infinite and use a far point on the ray as the target. Add your raytracing code, someone may be able to help with it.

Answer (score 0):

So from what I understood, you want your game object to move in 3D space to the direction of your cursor, which is in 2D space. You could try to get the game object's world location and use [Camera.WolrdToScreenPoint()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.WorldToScreenPoint.html). This gives you Vector3 where x and y are screen coordinates and z is camera world z coordinate. Then you can get your cursor position with [Input.mousePosition](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input-mousePosition.html). Now you have two points that you can use to calculate direction. (You decide if you want to use camera z position or set it to zero.)

```
Vector3 payerScreenPos = cam.WorldToScreenPoint(player.transform.position);
Vector3 direction = (playerScreenPos - Input.mousePosition).normalized;
```

You need to have a reference to the current camera (cam) and to your player.